# Save last login of User CakePHP3

Tags: authentication, save, cakephp-3.0

i try to save last login of connected user, but i have this error, my function is :

```
if ($this->Auth->user()) { // check user is logged in
        $this->User->id = $this->Auth->user('id'); // target correct record
        $this->User->saveField('lastlogin', date(DATE_ATOM)); // save login time
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect()); // redirect to default place
    }
```

And i have this error :

```
Notice (8): Indirect modification of overloaded property App\Controller\UsersController::$User has no effect [APP/Controller/UsersController.php, line 70]
Warning (2): Creating default object from empty value [APP/Controller/UsersController.php, line 70]
```

My user is connected, but the last login is not modified in table ! Why ?

Comment: That doesn't look like CakePHP 3.x at all.

Comment: Please read the documentation for CakePHP 3, specifically the migration guide for users coming from version 2. This code does not correspond at all with version 3

Comment: It's the Cake 3, saveField is remplace by save in Cake 3, but i have a same error ! i don't know !

Answer (score -1):

You used a wrong syntax in your code. Please read [cakephp 3.X cookbook, how to define model.](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html)